# How can I have .form-check-inline buttons in a separate line from their label?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm implementing a form containing some radio buttons. Using Bootstrap 4, I want to use `.form-check-inline` to have them horizontally aligned, but has the side effect of putting them in the same line as the input label:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Label</label>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input type="radio" name="test">
              Option 1
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input type="radio" name="test">
              Option 2
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

.. which does not look good to me.
I actually want the label to stay in its own line, with the radio buttons following in the next line. How do I achieve this while respecting Bootstrap patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is having three labels for two inputs valid and accessible? You might should ought to use a legend element for the first one.

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <legend>Legend</legend>

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="radio" name="test">
          Label 1
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="radio" name="test">
          Label 2
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u5cLwjbh/)**

Comment: Oh well, thank you, looks good now. But doesn't legend actually have to be used in conjunction with fieldsets? Referring to Bootstraps v4 form doc, I see now that legends are used for checks while labels are seemingly used for everything else.. wouldn't it make sense to use legend exclusively?

Comment: Legends are used to wrap multiple elements, whereas labels are linked by ID or markup structure to a single input. You may well want to employ a fieldset.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put **label** outside the **form** tag...
Like this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
     <label>Label</label> <!-- In here -->
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input type="radio" name="test">
              Option 1
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input type="radio" name="test">
              Option 2
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right, I meant under **form** tag and above **<div class="form-group">**

Comment: in Bootstrap, there are a lot of examples that label components like this

Comment: You'll want to update your answer, then. Maybe include links to references.